# Sorting very large amount of data in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a SSIS package in which I am taking 30 million records to sort. But this taking so much time. Is there any efficient way to sort large amount of data? Memory in the drive is less compare to the data....

Comment: Please post your select so we can hava a better idea of what you are trying to do.
does the table have many columns? are you sorting more than one column?

Comment: What column(s) are you sorting by? Is there an index on the table for that column (or those columns)?

Comment: Although the question is unclear, I suspect the OP is talking about the SSIS Sort Transformation, which is an in-memory operation that doesn't use any physical tables. Indeed, the data being sorted may have come from flat files or some other non-relational source. But the OP should clarify this, or it won't be possible to answer his question.

Comment: To followup with @Pondlife's comment, I too assume the OP is attempting to use the Sort transformation. If the data is sourced from something that supports sorting, always do it there. Databases are far better at sorting data than SSIS. They have structures in place to support it, SSIS has to do it on the fly. Additionally, sort is slow (fully blocking operation) and a resource hog-the memory cost of the data flow is doubled each time there is a blocking transformation in there. Thus, you have 30GB of memory available to SSIS, you split your memory to 15 before sort, 15 after sort.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting gets way more expensive when the recordset is too large to fit into memory.

One possible solution is to sort the input while it is building.  You can do this by adding an index to the input table, like:

```
create clustered index IX_YourTable_SortColumn on YourTable(SortColumn)
```

If the index can't be clustered, use `include` to add columns to the sorted index:

```
create index IX_YourTable_SortColumn on YourTable(SortColumn)
    include (col1, col2, col3)
```

This approach makes the previous step more expensive, and consumes more disk space, in order to have the records on disk in the right order.  You'd have to test to see if the tradeoff is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The sort in SSIS is horribly slow when dealing with large datasets. If you -need- in-SSIS sorting, you should be looking at either developing your own sort component, or use a third-party one like [NSort](http://www.ordinal.com/).